# How to simplify overriding props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an If statement and returning the same component with the extra props based on the state. Any idea how to simplify this? Can I use recursion? Any idea?

`iconRight` is only difference.

```
renderInput = () => {
    if (isLoading) {
      return (
        <Input
          iconRight={(
              <Spinner />
          )}
          autoComplete="off"
          id="unique-id-2"
          aria-autocomplete="both"
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <Input
        autoComplete="off"
        id="unique-id-2"
        aria-autocomplete="both"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spread props onto the component:

```
renderInput = () => {
    const props = {
        autoComplete: 'off',
        id: 'unique-id-2',
        'aria-autocomplete': 'off'
    };
    if (isLoading) {
      return (
        <Input
          iconRight={(
              <Spinner />
          )}
          {...props}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <Input {...props} />
    );
  }
}
```

But i'd suggest changing your `Input` component to accept a `loading` prop and let the `Input` component handle that logic. It'll make your consuming code a lot easier to read also.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function can be shortened to the following;

```
renderInput = () => (
    <Input
        iconRight={isLoading ? (<Spinner />) :  null}
        autoComplete="off"
        id="unique-id-2"
        aria-autocomplete="both"
    />
)
```

If you don't already, inside your `Input` component, you should check if the `iconRight` prop is not null, and only render it then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
renderInput = () =>(
        <Input
          iconRight={
           isLoading && (
              <Spinner />
          )}
          autoComplete="off"
          id="unique-id-2"
          aria-autocomplete="both"
        />
    )
```